# Removing the host name or server name or jboss domain name from jsessionid in Java

Tags: java, servlets, jboss, jsessionid, httpcookie

I am new to JBOSS server application deployment. Can any one help out of this issue. When I deployed the application in jboss server, jsessionid is displayed with double quotes and which has the server name. In the backend we are using Java.

eg: **SMFrdQAmPQchKx5c5gqbkzQH0g5IFxSOzyOiSkb.ftlap4265**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: After deploying the application in jboss server, cookies showing the jsessionid along with servername.